# I generated the code as below,but reset button is not displaying between start and finish buttons

Tags: java, blackberry, blackberry-storm

I generated the code as below, but reset button is not displaying between start and finish buttons. Any one help me to display the reset button?

Thanks in advance

```
final BitmapField mybitmapresetField = new BitmapField(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("res/images/start_button.png"),FOCUSABLE);
protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {

                layoutChild( mybitmapstartField, maxWidth, maxHeight);
                setPositionChild( mybitmapstartField, 140, 0);
                layoutChild( mybitmapresetField, maxWidth, maxHeight);
                setPositionChild( mybitmapresetField, 0, 0);

                layoutChild(mybitmapfinishField, maxWidth, maxHeight);
                setPositionChild(mybitmapfinishField, 280, 0);
                layoutChild(mybitmaplogoField, maxWidth, maxHeight);
                setPositionChild(mybitmaplogoField, 20, 440);

                layoutChild( mybitmaphowtoField, maxWidth, maxHeight);
                setPositionChild( mybitmaphowtoField, 140, 440);
                layoutChild( mybitmapm1Field, maxWidth, maxHeight);
                setPositionChild( mybitmapm1Field, 190, 60);
                layoutChild( mybitmapleftyrField, maxWidth, maxHeight);
                setPositionChild( mybitmapleftyrField, 120, 100);
                layoutChild( mybitmaprightyrField, maxWidth, maxHeight);
                setPositionChild( mybitmaprightyrField, 280, 100);
                layoutChild( backgroundBitmapbar1, maxWidth, maxHeight);
                setPositionChild( backgroundBitmapbar1, 10, 140);
                layoutChild( backgroundBitmapbar2, maxWidth, maxHeight);
                setPositionChild( backgroundBitmapbar2, 10, 180);
                layoutChild( backgroundBitmapbar3, maxWidth, maxHeight);
                setPositionChild( backgroundBitmapbar3, 10, 220);
                layoutChild( backgroundBitmapbar4, maxWidth, maxHeight);
                setPositionChild( backgroundBitmapbar4, 10, 260);
                layoutChild( backgroundBitmapbar5, maxWidth, maxHeight);
                setPositionChild( backgroundBitmapbar5, 10, 300);
                layoutChild( backgroundBitmapbar6, maxWidth, maxHeight);
                setPositionChild( backgroundBitmapbar6, 10, 340);

                layoutChild( timerCount , maxWidth, maxHeight);
                setPositionChild( timerCount , 274, 443);
                setExtent(Display.getWidth(),Display.getHeight());

            }

        };
        _vfm.add(mybitmapstartField) ;

        _vfm.add(mybitmapresetField) ;
        _vfm.add(mybitmapfinishField) ;
        _vfm.add(mybitmaplogoField) ;
        _vfm.add(mybitmapm1Field) ;
        _vfm.add(mybitmapleftyrField) ;
        _vfm.add(mybitmaprightyrField) ;
        _vfm.add( mybitmaphowtoField) ;
        _vfm.add(timerCount) ;
        _vfm.add(backgroundBitmapbar1) ;

        _vfm.add(backgroundBitmapbar2) ;
        _vfm.add(backgroundBitmapbar3) ;
        _vfm.add(backgroundBitmapbar4) ;
        _vfm.add(backgroundBitmapbar5) ;
        _vfm.add(backgroundBitmapbar6) ;

    this.add(_vfm);  
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling setPositionChild with a 0 coordinate for the reset field, a 140 coordinate for the start field, and a 280 coordinate for the finish field. You need to set the field's coordinate to something between 140 and 280, or else change the other coordinates.

Comment: i want to built my application as taking one listfield ,in that list field i want to put 12 images and 12 text .but i dont know how to use listfield ,so,plz, help me how to develop list field,give me sample code to implement

Comment: i developed a application with list field,in the list field i added 12 rows,in every column theare 7 fields.my problem is it is not scrolling,can u plz help me

Comment: See here: http://www.blackberryforums.com/developer-forum/166750-listfield-scrolling.html